# JavaScript RegExp to match time intervals

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get a RegExp which works in an online tool here to work in Javascript.

The working online RegExp can be found here: https://regex101.com/r/htldlR/2

The Javascript code that runs the same expression below fails

```js
function isInterval(value) {
    const regex = new RegExp(/^(?!.*(second|minute|hour|day|week|month|year).*\1)d+s+(?:second|minute|hour|day|week|month|year)s?(?: +d+s+(?:second|minute|hour|day|week|month|year)s?)*/, "gmi");

    console.log("MATCH "+value+" MATCH "+value.match(regex)+ " TEST "+regex.test(value))
    return regex.test(value);
}

const interval = "1 year 6 months 10 days 12 hours 30 minutes 30 seconds"

console.log(isInterval(interval));
```

The code is on jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/gp4orvj9/1/

I guess that the problem is something to do with escaping the expression.

Comment: Also make sure to click "EcmaScript" in the regex101 page

Comment: Duplicate of [Why does a RegExp with global flag give wrong results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1520800) - you have a global regex which you execute *twice*.

Answer (score 0):

If I copy the JavaScript Regex101 regex and do not use new RegExp then it works.
If you want to use new RegExp, you need to escape things like \s

I also save and return the test since you would need to reset if you want to console.log it

```js
function isInterval(value) {
    const regex = /^(?!.*(second|minute|hour|day|week|month|year).*\1)\d+\s+(?:second|minute|hour|day|week|month|year)s?(?: +\d+\s+(?:second|minute|hour|day|week|month|year)s?)*$/gmi
   const match = value.match(regex)
   const test = regex.test(value)
   console.log(`MATCH ${value}: ${match}\nTEST ${test}`)
   return test;
}

const interval = "1 year 6 months 10 days 12 hours 30 minutes 30 seconds"

console.log(isInterval(interval));
```

Comment: Thanks. This works - it's the escaping of \d and \s that makes all the difference